# Automatically refresh Cache

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, cache

I would like to refresh all cache at specified intervals, like once a day at midnight (as an example). How can I accomplish this?

I'm using CE 1.9.1.

Comment: set a cron job and clear cache

Comment: OK, basically I'm asking how to do that. How do I set a cronjob for this?

Comment: have you set magento cron on your server?

Comment: try [Aoe_CacheCleaner](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_CacheCleaner)

Comment: if you're refreshing cache at intervals, then i'd re-evaluate your implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If  in your magento system,`magento cron jobs are working properly` then 
you define `a cronjob` which ***fire on midnight and clear cache***.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <clean_cache_midnight><!-- identifier -->
             <schedule>
                 <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr> <!-- run cronjob on midnight -->
             </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>MyModule_Model_Group_Class_Name::functionName</model>
            </run>
        </clean_cache_midnight>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And class is

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Mycron
{
    public function functionName(){

     /**
     * Flush all magento cache
     */
     Mage::app()->cleanCache();
    }
}
```

### Full module:

create `config.xml` at  ***app/code/community/Amit/Cleancache/etc/***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Amit_Cleancache>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Amit_Cleancache>
</modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cleancache>
                <class>Amit_Cleancache_Model</class>
            </cleancache>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <clean_cache_midnight><!-- identifier -->
                 <schedule>
                     <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr> <!-- running cronjob on midnight -->
                 </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>cleancache/Fire::fireCacheonMidnight</model>
                </run>
            </clean_cache_midnight>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**File2:** create  `Fire.php`  at ***app/code/community/Amit/Cleancache/Model/***

**code:**

```
<?php
class Amit_Cleancache_Model_Fire
{
    public function fireCacheonMidnight(){

     /**
     * Flush all magento cache
     */
     Mage::app()->cleanCache();
    }
}
```

**File3:** module config file ***Amit_Cleancache.xml*** at ***app/etc/modules/***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Cleancache>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Amit_Cleancache>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: The config.xml generates this error: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 14 at column 14: Opening and ending tag mismatch: models line 0 and global
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

1.0.0 Amit_Cleancache_Model"

Comment: tag was not close..i have update the answer.. now check

Comment: Great, works like a charm!

Comment: @AmitBera How can i set cron job on my server, like every night autorefresh cache and reindex.

Comment: @AmitBera I have created simple code for clear the cache. The code is : https://justpaste.it/6rjvd and cron configuration : https://snag.gy/AZowtf.jpg. Still cron not working, is right what i did?

Comment: Not working form me in Magento 1.9.2.4. 
I added all your code but nothing was happened. Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

In Magento > cache management > the 3 last cache options :

Additional Cache Management 
Flush Catalog Images Cache  Pregenerated product images files.
Flush Swatch Images Cache   Pregenerated configurable swatches image files.
Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache  Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined to one file.

is it possible to flush these cache types using an auto cron job?

Reason being :

If I do not clear these caches regularly then the REDIS thing fails and everything crashes.

Thanks :)