# Installing Cron Scheduler on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, cron

How can I Install a Cron Scheduler on Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the scheduler extension?

If yes, then you can download the zip from github from 
the link: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Extract and paste the files and folder to your magento root.

Comment: Just the app folder? Also what I ultimately want to do is run a new cron job to clear cache every 12 hours. How can I do that?

Comment: you can use reference from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/automatically-refresh-cache

Comment: you can use "0 */12 * * *" expression to run the cron every in every 12 hours

Comment: So once I implement the full module on my server. What should I do? What commands should I run?

Comment: So I added the 3 files on my server... What should I do now?

Comment: i hope you are following from the "full module section". And if so, then you are successfully created a cron to run every 12th hour clear the cache. And if you have also installed the scheduler , then you can check your model name " cleancache/Fire::fireCacheonMidnight " which is given in the config.xml file in the admin section from : Sysetm > Scheduler > job configuration

Comment: Hi seems like it worked for one day and then it did not the second day. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi getting a http 500 error when trying to access the AOE Scheduler on admin. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure , you have uploaded all the module files ? please try clearing your magento cache and then try. Or better rename the cache folder from /var and then run the aadmin

Answer (score 1):

It is still abstract in the way that you don’t really run jobs directly, instead, you use cron syntax to setup periodical method execution via Magento scheduler that works on top of system’s cron utility.

[image]

**First you need crontab.xml inside your custom module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default"> <!-- Doesn't need to be unique -->
    <job name="cron_example" instance="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Cron\Example" method="execute">
        <schedule></schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

**Configuration above is to make sure that every minute, 
[VendorName][VendorName]\Cron\Example:execute() is run which would (according the code below log it’s name every minute.)**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\VendorName\Cron;
class Example {

protected $_logger;

public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function execute() {
    $this->_logger->info(__METHOD__);
    return $this;
}
}
```

**and then ::**

```
magento cron:run [--group="cron_group_name"]
```

Comment: What I ultimately want to do is run a new cron job to clear cache every 12 hours. How can I do that? I am running Magento 1.6.0.2

Comment: Okay here is a [example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/automatically-refresh-cache) for cron job to clear cache, which will help you.

Comment: you can pass the method in php fine, on above example which i posted.

Mage::app()->cleanCache();