# How can I run a new cron job to clear cache every 12 hours?

Tags: magento-1, cron, crontab

How can I run a new cron job to clear cache every 12 hours? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automatically refresh Cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/automatically-refresh-cache) is the exact thing you want, A defined cronjob which fire on midnight (you can modify as per your need -12 hours) which clears the cache.