# How to enable extensions through terminal?

Tags: magento-1, extensions, command-line

Is there a way to enable and disable extensions in version 1.x via the command line?

How can I enable an extension through terminal?

What is the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CLI command for Magento 1 extensions as this was added in Magento 2.  If you check the file from the installed extension found in `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`, there will be a node `<active>true</active>` that should be `true` when enabled and `false` when disabled.  Additionally, there is a data-value in `core_config_data` for each module that should be `0` if the extension is enabled and `1` when it is disabled.  You can select that with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM core_config_data
WHERE path = 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Vendor_Module';
```

From there, just make sure your cache is cleared, log out & back in.

Comment: Would it work with this module? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/automatically-refresh-cache

Comment: It is already set to active

Comment: In the case of the linked module, your select statment's condition would be `WHERE path = 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Amit_Cleancache';`.  Also, make sure to log out and back in after clearing the cache.

Comment: Where would I write that? In terminal?

Comment: It is actually easier for you to go through magento-admin then.  Go to `Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`, then find your module and make sure it is set to `Enable`.  It might also be wise to check values under different Configuration Scopes (dropdown at top-left) to make sure it is not being overridden.

Comment: It's not showing up there. Do you think I have to clear cache?

Comment: Yes, and log out, then back in....

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it enabled. I don't see any settings to it do you think once enabled it should begin working? It's basically a module that runs and clears cache every 12 hours.

Comment: I don't see any settings to it do you think once enabled it should begin working?

Comment: If your [cron jobs](https://amasty.com/blog/configure-magento-cron-job/) are enabled/configured properly, then it should be fine.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help today! I truly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

```
$ n98-magerun.phar dev:module:disable MyVendor_MyModule
$ n98-magerun.phar dev:module:disable --codepool="community"
```